# joomla - running multiple queries in one model

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a Joomla 1.5 MVC component that runs one view with many different layouts that all work fine.  I'm trying to incorporate multiple functions in the model to pull from different tables.  What the second (and third) function tries to pull is dependent on a variable passed through the first function:

```
function mlsData($column) {

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $mlsnumber = JRequest::getVar('mlsnum');
    $query = "
      SELECT *
        FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__mls')."
        WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('MSTMLSNO')." = ".$db->quote($mlsnumber).";
    ";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadRow();
    return $row[$column];

}

function agentData($column) {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $agentuid = mlsData(0);
    $query = "
      SELECT *
        FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__agents')."
        WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('AGTBRDIDMM')." = ".$db->quote($agentuid).";
    ";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadRow();
    return $row[$column];
}

function agencyData($column) {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $agencyid = agentData(7);
    $query = "
      SELECT *
        FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__agency')."
        WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('OFFFRMID')." = ".$db->quote($agencyid).";
    ";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $row = $db->loadRow();
    return $row[$column];
}
```

Everything runs fine until, in my model, I try to pass an argument through the second function, `agentData()`.  I can't tell what errors I'm getting because nothing displays on the page.  and by that I mean, no content, no template, nothing.  It literally only displays this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly enable error reporting.Put the below code in your file and check if any error comes-

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

The reason could be that you are calling function directly and it is in the class. Use this operator and see if it works.

change `$agentuid = mlsData(0);` to `$agentuid = $this->mlsData(0);`

same for this- `$agencyid = agentData(7);` to `$agencyid = $this->agentData(7);`

Hope this will help you.